# Benefits of jRuby with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I'm currently considering moving to jRuby, and I'm still unsure how everything will work, but let's consider this hypothetical situation.

A `user 1` loads a page in my app which takes about 2.5 seconds, and at about `500ms` in the execution a `user 2` tries to open different page which takes 1 second to load.

If my estimate is correct, this is what would happen if you ran it in MRI with single process :

1. User 1 waits for 2,5 seconds for his page to load
2. User 2 waits for 3 seconds for his page to load (2 seconds waiting for user 1 to complete the loading of his page, and 1 second for his page to finish rendering)

Is my estimate correct?

And let's say if I ran the same app under jRuby this would happen :

1. User 1 waits 2,5 seconds for his page to load
2. User 2 waits for 1 or more seconds but less than 3, depending how much of the memory/cpu the request from user 1 takes

Is my other estimate correct? Of course assuming your code is thread safe. If my estimate is incorrect please correct me, or if it is correct, do I need to make sure that some config is set at rails app level or should I be careful about something else other than thread safe code?

### Update

I've just done a small jRuby POC app, used the warbler gem to build a war file, and deployed a war to a Tomcat web server. I don't think my estimate was correct for jRuby, this is what I observed :

1. User 1 waits 2,5 seconds for his page to load
2. User 2 waits for 3 seconds

Which is identical to MRI, in terms of request processing, shouldn't jRuby process these in parallel?

Comment: if your goal is to serve multiple requests asynchronously - I'd advise you visit a mutli-process web-server like [unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn)

Comment: @Anthony yes that is my goal. Would I get the same with Tomcat (java servlet container and app server), using along with jruby?

Answer (score 1):

we're talking were hypothetical things (and assumptions)

if *"loads a page in my app which takes about 2.5 seconds"* all users will keep loading this thing (concurrently) unless of course you do some caching or store it after the first load for other users.

the difference is that in MRI whenever Ruby code is executed (not waiting on IO such as a database or loading something from http://) 2 threads won't run concurrently, while in JRuby they will.

if you're seeing `User 2 waits for 3 seconds` on JRuby it means that smt is blocking multiple requests e.g. there's a `Mutex` somewhere along the way (e.g. `Rack::Lock`).